# How do I set a custom button background for a Metro app for all states

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to use my own bitmaps for my buttons for a Metro style Windows 8 app.  I can set the background brush for a button to my own ImageBrush and that works fine, except for the hover and pressed states.  I cannot figure out how to set the bitmaps for them.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit) has an ImageButton control that allows to define images for all states if that is what you need. You can also check its default template in [Generic.xaml](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/15513#246009) to see how it uses the bitmaps based on multiple overlaid Image controls (check e.g. PART_HoverStateImage) and visual states that control opacities of these Image controls.
If you are lazy - you can also use just two bitmaps and use semi-transparent bitmap defined using the PressedStateImageSource overlaid on top of the bitmap defined with IdleStateImageSource to show a hover state. Or you can go fully lazy and use just a single bitmap for idle state and let the control generate bitmaps for the other two states by setting GeneratePressedState and GenerateHoverState to true - that generates these bitmaps by "lightening" the idle state image with some basic image processing. The Toolkit also has a sample app with a page that demonstrates the use of the ImageButton control in multiple ways.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will check out the toolkit and see if it will work for me, but are you telling me that there is no straightforward way to set these states without using a third party solution? That seems hard to believe. I mean why let me set the background at all if I cannot set it for all the states?  What are the chances that if I change the background for the non-pressed state that I will be happy with the default backgrounds for the other states?

Comment: Of course chances are you won't. Still, it serves to show how you can do it. You set a custom control template on a button that has all the images you want and use visual states to reveal images for different states. ImageButton also shows how you can create a general solution to the problem if you have a lot of buttons that need to show different bitmaps depending on state. By using it or creating something similar you can create many buttons by just specifying ImageSource for each state instead of creating a separate template for each button.

Comment: Yes, it was very useful, I always find working examples to be the best documentation.  Thanks.